# How to rewrite rule in web.config file

Tags: regex, url, web-config

Need one help.  we have one rule rewritten like this in the web.config file.

```
<DomainRedirectRule>      
        <LookFor>http://(www.)?sitename.com(/)?(default.aspx)?</LookFor>
        <SendTo>http://www.sitename.com/test</SendTo>
      </DomainRedirectRule>
```

Now the new requirement is when some one enter http://sitename.com/asdf it should go to the destination url instead of returning 404 page.

Can somebody please advise how should i rewrite the above the rule to make this happen.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `http://(www.)?sitename.com(/|default.aspx)?$` in your LookFor rule. My guess is that with the `$` symbol, it would match only the addresses that ends up with what you're trying to express.